# Phonegap app has slow startup time when using mobile data, but fast on WiFi

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

My app has a login screen that is shown on startup, but there are no ajax calls made to my server until after the login button is pressed. There is no code that makes a call to my server immediately when the app starts, so there really isn't any reason for it to be downloading a huge amount of data on startup right?

I am however using Urban Airship for push notifications, could it be that that? It starts almost instantly when using WiFi, but on a perfect 4G LTE connection it takes around 15-20 seconds.

Comment: Do any of the JS/CSS/HTML/images/fonts required for your app load over the network or are all of those loaded from local URLs using assets you ship in the www folder of your Cordova project?

Comment: @SimonPrickett All my images and scripts are packaged in the app and loaded locally yes. The only thing that is loaded remotely on startup that I can see is the Google Maps API. And I am also registering push notifications on startup but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks - suspect it might be a plugin then, you might be onto something with Urban Airship but which others are you using?

Comment: @SimonPrickett Wow! You were right on the plugin. Before I went with Urban Airship I tried out a couple other notification plugins and still had them installed. I uninstalled the ones I wasn't using and it works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks I reframed as an answer, so that this question can have a proper accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given we've established you are loading all of your HTML, CSS, font and image assets locally then startup time should not be affected by having to load any of those over the slower network.

The only other thing I can think of would be that one or more plugins in your application are trying to do network operations on startup, some of which may be failing because for example the plugin is misconfigured or just plain written incorrectly.

I would suggest you look at the plugins you are using as your next focus area for debugging.